# Removing Sidebar on Product Tag sites

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, sidebar

Hello mostly logical fellows

I'm currently trying to remove the sidebars on the Product Tag pages on this Wordpress with Woocomerce website: https://zoonomia.ch

Example Product Tag page: https://zoonomia.ch/tag/hanf-natur/

This hook Code in the funcations.php child-theme doesn't work and I don't understand why not.

```
if ( is_product_tag() ) {  
remove_action('woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10);}
```

The Theme is from Kallyas. Categories e.g. have an Option in it's Theme to disable sidebars but not Product Tags.

Do you have an idea for a solution?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

The product tag archive page uses archive.php if your theme doesn't have a specific woocommerce archive page template.

If your theme have woocomerce template look into `woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php` and see if that page have condition to disable the sidebar or not. Post some snippet of that page to get better idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll look into it asap.